# How to populate address in patient card?

Tags: health-cloud

I am trying to populate address to the patient card. I have added the Address to the patient card configuration. Initially Entered the address in Lead Record and try to convert to patient. But still the value is not populated. Can someone help where did I go wrong? Did I use the correct object and field  names in the patient card configuration?
[image: Patient card][image: Patient card Configuration]